# After migration cannot access Magento 2 backend anymore

Tags: magento2, admin

I just got the migration working - all categories, products etc. seem to be fine in the frontend.

My backend was at: `http://localhost/magento2/admin_1bcprj/`
env.php:

```
return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_1bcprj',
  ),
```

and `web/unsecure/base_url` and the secure version are pointing to: `http://localhost/magento2/`

But in the browser under: `http://localhost/magento2/admin_1bcprj/` I only get a 404 from Magento. Is there any other setting somewhere that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find you answer in Alan Kent's article http://alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/